# two jquery script conflict

Tags: jquery, html

i have a problem with two jquery scripts :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"</script>
    <script src="js/jquery.counter.js"</script>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mSimpleSlidebox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.beemoNav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

when i put :

`<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"</script>`

before

```
<script src="js/jquery.counter.js"</script>
```

scrollbar work, but not counter

and vice&versa

code for run script :

```
<script>
    $('.comdepress').mCustomScrollbar();
    $('.counter').counter(); // compteur de giga
</script>
```

here is error i have in firebug :

```
TypeError: $(...).counter is not a function

$('.counter').counter(); // compteur de giga
```

don't understand why

link for two script i use : 
[scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)
[counter](http://sophilabs.com/blog/jquery-counter-plugin)

thanks

Comment: `<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"` - its a typo or you missed a closing `>`?

Comment: i'm very tired, it work now ty, +1 : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$.noConflict();`

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

```
<script>$.noConflict();</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.counter.js"></script>
                     ------------^
```

instead of

```
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"</script>
<script src="js/jquery.counter.js"</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in the code

```
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"</script>
```

missing `>` before closing tag `</script>`

Answer (score 0):

simply use noConflict(); before declaring the js fi